# how do I read this mysql select query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to optimize this mysql select query but I dont know how to read this. Was wondering if someone could explain what this query is doing in terms of thw WHERE clause.

```
SELECT `id`, `size`, `download`, `mirror1`, `mirror2`, `mirror3` 
FROM `entries` 
WHERE (`flags` & '3') = '0';
```

Comment: you want to apply bitwise and or simply concat string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's doing a bitwise `AND` operator on flags, read about it here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_AND#AND

3 in binary is 11, so it's checking to see if lower two bits of flags are NOT set (e.g. they're 0), since the result of the AND operator must be 0 according to where clause.

Examples (assume flags has the following values):

```
Ex 1:    11101000 <-- WHERE clause would be true, since lower two bits are 0
Ex 2:    11111010 <-- WHERE clause would be false, since lower two bits are NOT 0
```

Comment: +1 Possibly worth noting that there's an implicit conversion of the `'3'` from character to numeric value 3 (and similarly of the `'0'`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're aiming at the `&`. This is a [`bitwise AND`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-and).

A good explanation of how it works can be found in this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation):

> A bitwise AND takes two binary representations of equal length and
>   performs the logical AND operation on each pair of corresponding bits.
>   The result in each position is 1 if the first bit is 1 and the second
>   bit is 1; otherwise, the result is 0. In this, we perform the
>   multiplication of two bits; i.e., 1 × 0 = 0 and 1 × 1 = 1. For
>   example:

```
    0101 (decimal 5)
AND 0011 (decimal 3)
  = 0001 (decimal 1)
```

This technique is often used to store the state, user permissions or similar stuff in a very compact form. I'm assuming the `3` are two certain states which the query checks against:

```
00000000 <- TRUE
00000001 <- FALSE
00000010 <- FALSE
00000011 <- FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure that it is in fact " WHERE (`flags` & '3') = '0'; "?  Would it be " WHERE (`flags` & 3) = 0; " which makes more sense?

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

select the id, size, download, mirror1, mirror2 and mirror3 fields from the entries table where flags as a binary number AND'ed with 3 is equal to zero.

Flags are commonly stored as bits which is converted to a number for storage. As a flag is normally on or off, this corresponds to binary 0 and 1. So 0 could be off and 1 could be on. So a sequence of four flags may be represented in binary as: 0 0 1 1 , (off, off, on, on) which is equivalent to decimal 3.

To satisfy the condition that a number AND'ed with decimal 3 (binary 11) gives zero, the number would have to have the two lowest bits as zero, so (in binary): 1 1 0 0, or 10100 etc would return zero, because an AND only returns 1 if both inputs are 1.